# Matplotlib: AssertionError in plotting errorbars

Tags: matplotlib, errorbar

I am trying to plot a regression fit plot with scatter values and regression fit.

Attached is the excel file with data from dropbox and the desired output graph (made in sigmaplot)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/czwq78yyy6vymaj/aniso.xlsx?dl=0

[image]

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data_x = pd.read_excel('aniso.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_cols='B', skiprows=2)
data_36 = pd.read_excel('aniso.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_cols='H', skiprows=2)
data_37 = pd.read_excel('aniso.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_cols='N')
data_38 = pd.read_excel('aniso.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_cols='O')
data_39 = pd.read_excel('aniso.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_cols='A')
plt.plot(data_x[2:21], data_36[2:21], 'h', color='#1f77b4', label='protein concentration')
plt.plot(data_37, data_38, color='#d62728', ls='--', label='regression fit')
plt.errorbar(data_x[2:21], data_36[2:21], yerr=data_39[2:21])
plt.show()
```

When running this code, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2931, in xywhere
    assert len(xs) == len(ys)
AssertionError
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error comes from the `errorbar` call, not for instance from the second `plot` (you don't use slicing there)? Can you post the entire error trace, not just the last line?

Comment: You have not been consistent with how you `skiprows`. Try printing out `data_x`, `data_36` and `data_39`. You'll see that they're different lengths, and that the headers are being read in incorrectly. Also note that because column B has a 2-line header, it will need to be read in differently to the other columns with only 1-line headers. Also, if you `skiprows` when you read the data in, you probably don't need to also slice the data between `[2:21]`, since the skiprows should take care of removing the items at the start. I haven't added this as an answer since I haven't tested it out.

Comment: @tom I made my data consistent and removed the skiprows. When I printed my data, everything looked okay. However, when I tried to plot the graph with the errorbar, I got the following error: **File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2964, in extract_err
    raise ValueError("err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 "
ValueError: err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 or 2xN array-like ]**

Comment: Try making the errors into a numpy array rather than a data frame?

Comment: @tom pardom my ignorance, I am not sure what do you mean. The only way I know to read an excel file is by pandas only. Can you please edit this line where I read the data_39 values - `data_39 = pd.read_excel('aniso.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_cols='A')`

Comment: I'm guessing here. Try `yerr=data_39.values` ?

Comment: encountered this:`TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')`

Answer (score 2):

`plt.errorbar(x, y)` strongly takes float or array-like object. I will suggest:

`plt.errorbar(np.array(x), np.array(y))`

It worked for me!